# Search digit from Integer value of 10

Tags: search

Want to search within the number for given value like number is 123456789 or 3022156982. I want if I enter 221 it should display 3022156982 full number or any other related number within the list just like putting filter which contains value of 221. The list of values are in database field. It should show all values where 221 appears. just we use like command for string for searching within text.

Answer (score -1):

Put this number into a variable and check condition using if statement: if given_num in variable:
.                             return True